# Parsing cross domain JSON, when there is an error

Tags: jquery, json

I am using `$.getJSON` to grab some data from a remote server. Note that I have no control over how the JSON is formatted or returned. I am using this code:

```
$(function(){
    var API = "https://ratesjson.fxcm.com/DataDisplayer?jsoncallback=?";
    $.getJSON(API, function(json) {
        var Symbol = json.results[0].Symbol;
        console.log('Symbol : ' + Symbol);
    });
});
```

I get this error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: null is not a function

I've taken a look at the JSON and I can see that before the object there is the string including `Null`. Any way around this? You can see the JSON and its error here: https://ratesjson.fxcm.com/DataDisplayer

Comment: Your `console.log` has error i.e. it should have been `console.log('Symbol : ' + Symbol);` Also.. if you are sure that null will present at any cost in the response, then just replace/remove it and then get the result..

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question. The error still persists, the actual first word in the returned JSON is 'null'. I know 'first word' isn't the right term, it is before the object name though. Click the link at the end of the question to see the data.

Comment: It is not a valid `json` then. You need to modify it.. But you are saying you have no control over it.. Hard to give solution to this..

Comment: There are also unnecessary commas after each last property in array

Comment: Again, I have no control over how the JSON is set up or returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API you're calling returns JSONP, not JSON, so you're best to use `$.ajax` with the relevant parameters provided. Try this:

```
var API = "https://ratesjson.fxcm.com/DataDisplayer";
$.ajax({
    url: API,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(json) {
        console.log(json);
    }
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/g124yrc0/)

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Try using $.ajax() over $.get(). It gives you full control to your ajax request.
See below example.

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "https://ratesjson.fxcm.com/DataDisplayer?jsoncallback=?",
  method: "POST",
  data: { id : '1' },
  dataType: "html"
});

request.done(function( msg ) {
  $( "#log" ).html( msg );
});

request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

More details :
[Jquery Tutorial]  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: That brings Cross Domain Origin issues back into play "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" which is why I went with $.getJSON. Using your example, and changing dataType:"html", to dataType: "json" gets around that but the original issue persists